# Google Maps API suggest different addresses

Tags: google-maps

Do you know a way I can resolve address by a mistyped one using the Google Maps API? I am looking for something like this code:

```
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

function showAddress(address) {
  geocoder.getLatLng(
    address,
    function(point) {
      if (!point) {
        alert(address + " not found");
      } else {
        map.setCenter(point, 13);
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        map.addOverlay(marker);
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(address);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

But instead of showing "address not found", I'd like to extend it and return some suggestions if any. Google Maps provides this functionality but can't seem to find it in the API.

Comment: You might want to upgrade to version 3 of the API. Version 2 is deprecated, and version 3 has an autocomplete in the Places Library

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe checkout these:**

> Fetching auto-complete suggestions with Geocoder:
>   http://tech.cibul.org/geocode-with-google-maps-api-v3/

And if all else fails, seek out the Geocoding API for some insight!

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding

Answer (score 0):

JJ, Google Maps does not perform address verification. In other words, the maps API will not tell you that an address is good or bad, but it will return its best guess to you. I work with address verification for SmartyStreets, so I have seen this quite a bit...

If you want to ensure that an address exists (US-based, at least) as well as fix typos and get suggestions and such, look into a CASS-Certified service. That's a buzzword in the mailing industry but applies to all other online and offline transactions as well. Vendors of these authorized services may have an API.

As a guide, you can reference our [LiveAddress API](http://www.smartystreets.com/Products/LiveAddress-API/) to start your own research about verifying addresses and getting nearest-match suggestions. I'll be more than happy to personally help you with any other questions along the lines of this one.